# Somar 02 campos dos campos vindos do BD Mysql

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço para que, o usuário digitar os valores em 02 campos o resultado dessa soma aparecer automaticamente no campo ValorFinal[]? Esses campos estão vindo do banco de dados.

```
while($peListar = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlListar){
    .....
    $listar .= "<td style='".$fundo."'><input type='text' name='ValorI[]'  class='md-form-control'  value=''></td>";
    $listar .= "<td style='".$fundo."'><input type='text' name='ValorII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>";
    $listar .= "<td style='".$fundo."'><input type='text' name='ValorFinal[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>";
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma, selecionando a linha do `input` onde os valores estão sendo inseridos, buscando e somando os valores dos dois primeiros `input`s:

```js
// input com name iniciado por "ValorI", ou seja,
// vai pegar tanto o "ValorI" quanto o "ValorII"
$("[name^='ValorI']").on("input", function(){
   
   var parent = $(this).closest("tr"); // seleciona a linha TR
   
   // converto os valores em número. Se for vazio, assume 0
   var valor1 = parseFloat($("[name='ValorI[]']", parent).val()) || 0;
   var valor2 = parseFloat($("[name='ValorII[]']", parent).val()) || 0;
   
   // insiro a soma no campo "ValorFinal[]" da respectiva linha
   $("[name='ValorFinal[]']", parent).val(valor1+valor2);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorI[]'  class='md-form-control'  value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorFinal[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorI[]'  class='md-form-control'  value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorFinal[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorI[]'  class='md-form-control'  value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorII[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='ValorFinal[]' class='md-form-control' value=''></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Olá dvd, funcionou da forma como passou, mas me perdoe, esqueci de mencionar um detalhe. Os valor total da soma, será dividido por 2 Coloquei da seguinte forma: (valor1+valor2)/2, mas ele só calculou o primeiro campo.

Comment: Se colocar assim: `$("[name='ValorFinal[]']", parent).val((valor1+valor2)/2);` o resultado será, por exemplo: `valor1 = 100` + `valor2 = 60`, soma = `160`, dividido por `2`, resultado = `80`.

Comment: Desculpe novamente dvd, funcionou sim. Foi um erro meu aqui. Obrigado